# Eliminate "Printing Page 1 of Document" message

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, printing

I have this routine that prints labels, both in preview mode on the screen and to the label printer.  Before each print operation starts, an annoying dialog box is displayed on the screen for a brief moment that is labeled "Printing" and in the body says "Page 1 of document" with a "Cancel" button.  I found one reference that said I could eliminate this by using a statement like the following before printing:

```
MyPowderlabel.PrintController = new System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController();
```

This seems to have had no effect.

Here's the code:

```
private void PrintLabel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   // This routine starts up the print operation for the current label
try
{
   PrintDocument MyPowderlabel;
   MyPowderlabel = new PrintDocument();
   PaperSize PS = null; //Label dimensions for printer are in units of .01"
   PS = new PaperSize("Custom Size", 134, 118 );  // 3.4 cm wide x 3 cm high
   MyPowderlabel.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = PS;
   MyPowderlabel.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false;
   MyPowderlabel.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(MyPowderlabel_PrintPage);
   MyPowderlabel.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printersList.Text;
   //  Display the label in the print preview box
   printPreviewControl1.Document = MyPowderlabel;
   printPreviewControl1.Document.PrintController = new System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController();

   printPreviewControl1.Show();

   //The next statement is needed to insure that the label preview will be displayed for at least
   //a short time before it gets erased before the next barcode is processed.
   Application.DoEvents();
   if (!ckPrintPreview.Checked)
    {
      // Send the label to the selected (hard copy) printer 
      MyPowderlabel.PrintController = new System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController();
      MyPowderlabel.Print();
    }
}
catch (Exception EX)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error while trying to send label to printer\r\n" + EX.Message);
}
}
```

Comment: Please supply your printing code, mainly the part that starts the printing.

Comment: Is this dialog coming from the printer driver?

Comment: This did work for me. I print PDF's using Sprite.PDF and ran into the same problem. MyPowderlabel.PrintController = new System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController(); solved it.